# Why in writing ":" - in the middle of code after the line - the code does not fall

Tags: php

Accidentally I discovered that code does not fall, if you write something like this:

```
<?php
fgfhfghfhgfhfh:
```

It resembles the following code

```
<?php
if(true):
endif;
```

But still, I expected errors, warnings, or something else ...

**Can anyone explain this behavior?**

**UPDATE:**
I know how it works:

**But the question remains, why considered code is correct?**

I can not write:

```
if(true):
```

OR

```
true?:
```

It will be a mistake, but if you write like this:

```
true    :
```

All perfectly!

**In the documentation:**

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures;
>   namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic
>   form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon
>   (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;,
>   or endswitch;, respectively.

*But my code - without closing brace*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because it considers your garbage a label for use with [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.goto.php)

*Children, don't try this at home - bad practice!*

```
echo "Let's loop!";

abc:
echo "Hello!";
goto abc;
```

The above example will create an infinite loop printing "Let's loop!" once and then printing "Hello!" all the time.

Comment: There is no  matter for a consideration here, it is a label ;)